# warning: incorrect argument passed to function

Tags: php, cakephp, warnings, cakephp-3.0

I have a function `beforeMarshal ()` located in `ModelTable.php`.  This function executes correctly before the request data is saved however I get php warnings each time the data is saved.

```
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, ArrayObject $data, ArrayObject $options)
{
    $ip = $data['ip'];
    $data['iplong'] = ip2long($ip);
}
```

> Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to App\Model\Table\ServersTable::beforeMarshal() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\Event, instance of Cake\Event\Event given
>
> Warning (4096): Argument 2 passed to App\Model\Table\ServersTable::beforeMarshal() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\ArrayObject, instance of ArrayObject given
>
> Warning (4096): Argument 3 passed to App\Model\Table\ServersTable::beforeMarshal() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\ArrayObject, instance of ArrayObject given

If I set debug to false everything is fine, but this isn't a great solution.

Comment: there may be `use` statements at the top of your script. Make sure the classes listed there match the one pointed by the error message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably a [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) issue. The error is that the function wants a precise type of object and it receives an other one.

I'm assuming `beforeMarshal()` is your own custom function and it is placed in the namespace `App\Model\Table` (as it belongs to the `ModelTable` class).

Furthermore, you are probably calling it from an other file, where you haven't specified the namespace, so it considers itself in global namespace.

either

- type hint the right object types in your function definition
- globally `use` the right object type in `ModelTable.php`

**precise type hint**

change your function definition to:

```
public function beforeMarshal(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
```

notice the backslashes. They instruct the function to start at global namespace when considering object types.

**global `use`**

at the very top of your `ModelTable.php` script (or the one containing the function) add this:

```
use
    Cake\Event\Event,
    ArrayObject;
```

so that in the whole script, any use of the `Event` and `ArrayObject` types will use the right one without specifying the whole name each time.

#### Which one to choose

opinions follow

I prefer to use `use` at the top of my scripts. It prevents any kind of misuse of types in this specific script, and when I have to change `ALL\Templating\Parser` to `ALL\Parser` I only have to do it at one place.

specifying the whole object namespace path each time is bothersome and a little bit more error-prone, but may have advantages; I haven't experienced them and haven't stopped the global approach since I started using it.

Answer (score -3):

Just remove Event, ArrayObject keywords and simply write in following way:

```
public function beforeMarshal($event, $data, $options)
{
    $ip = $data['ip'];
    $data['iplong'] = ip2long($ip);
}
```

I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: That's most definitely not the correct way, as you're just working around the actual problem.